# Transform Multiple Columns Into One With Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, series

I have a dataframe structured as such:
[image: dataframe snapshot]

**I am wondering what the most efficient way is in pandas to create a new column "stage" that extracts any value that isn't 'None' in the four columns and use that value for the 'stage' column.**  The remaining four columns can then be dropped after the stage column has extracted out any value that isn't None in each row.

Here is another snapshot of the unique values of each column involved:
[image: unique values]

Please note that the values in the columns in question are string type and None isn't actually Nonetype.

Comment: Do you mind to share an actual dataframe and code instead of the pics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['New']=df[['A','B','C']].replace('None','').sum(1)
df
Out[1477]: 
      A     B     C New
0  None     B  None   B
1     A  None  None   A
2  None  None     C   C
```

Data input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['None','A','None'],'B':['B','None','None'],'C':['None','None','C']})
```

Comment: thanks! that worked. I don't understand the .sum(1) portion of the code though.  Can you explain whats going on there?

Comment: @KeenanBurke-Pitts sum(1), is summing the df row by row , it it is string , it will join them together :-) (PS: I replace all None to be '')

Comment: @KeenanBurke-Pitts yw~ happy coding

Answer (score 3):

Consider `combine_first`, assuming *None* is not a string literal `'None'`.

```
df['stage'] = df['doggo'].combine_first(df['floorfer'])\
                         .combine_first(df['pupper'])\ 
                         .combine_first(df['puppo'])
```

Alternatively, for DRY-er approach, use `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
...

df['stage'] = reduce(lambda x,y: x.combine_first(y), 
                     [df['doggo'], df['floorfer'], df['pupper'], df['puppo']])
```