# How to combine multiple columns to single column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is the sample data provided and I need to combine the columns to single column which consists of all the fruit names without any Nan Values and also total column should'nt be changed.

```
|Fruit1  | Fruit2| Fruit3| Total|
|:------ | :----:| :----:|-----:|
|NaN     | Apple | NaN.  | 20.  |
|Pear    | NaN   | NaN.  | 40.  |
|NaN.    | NaN   | orange| 50.  |
|Mango   | NaN   | NaN.  | 43.  |
|NaN     | banana| NaN.  | 35.  |
```

This should be the output:

```
|Fruits  | Total|
|------- | -----|
|Apple   | 20.  |
|Pear    | 40.  |
|Orange  | 50.  |
|Mango   | 43.  |
|banana  | 35.  |
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`bfill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'fruit_1': [None, 'Pear', None, None], 
    'fruit_2': ['Apple', None, None, None], 
    'fruit_3': [None, None, 'Orange', None]})

df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0].rename('fruits') # returns
```

```
0     Apple
1      Pear
2    Orange
3      None
Name: fruits, dtype: object
```

(or [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and use the last column)

It also works for rows containing `None` only.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have only one non-NaN per row, you can `stack`:

```py
df.stack().droplevel(1).to_frame(name='Fruits')
```

Output:

```
   Fruits
0   Apple
1    Pear
2  Orange
3   Mango
4  banana
```

##### Handling rows with only NaNs:

```py
df.stack().droplevel(1).to_frame(name='Fruits').reindex(df.index)
```

Output assuming banana is a NaN:

```
   Fruits
0   Apple
1    Pear
2  Orange
3   Mango
4     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what if we want to retain rows that all have NaN values.

Comment: You can `reindex` with the original index

Comment: What if we have other columns other than fruits in the data frame and we don't want to change the data of that column.

Comment: Best IMO would be to subselect these columns, `stack` as I did, then `join` back to DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

I think this should give the desired output -

`df['Fruit1'].fillna(df['Fruit2'])`

Comment: However, this is only applicable for two columns. For more you can refer to ```bfill()```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `combine_first` here:

```py
df["Fruits"] = df["Fruit1"].combine_first(df["Fruit2"])
```

We can also use `np.where`:

```py
df["Fruits"] = np.where(df["Fruit1"].isnull(), df["Fruit2"], df["Fruit1"])
```

Comment: what if there are 3 or more columns of similar format and we need to combine all 3 to 1 column

Comment: That's not the question which was asked, nor what anyone answered.  If you had three columns, I would need to see what the data looks like.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I have updated the question. I would appreciate If you could help out.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a modification of an approach from [Transform Multiple Columns Into One With Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47994917/transform-multiple-columns-into-one-with-pandas) to combine columns:

```
df['new'] = df.fillna('').sum(1)
```

**Explanation**

- replace all nan values with an empty string
- sum(1), is summing the df row by row.  Since values in row are strings, it will join them together

**Example Usage**

```
from io import StringIO

# Create DataFrame from OP data
s = '''Fruit1,Fruit2,Fruit3
NaN,Apple,NaN
Pear,NaN,NaN
NaN,NaN,Orange
Mango,NaN,NaN
NaN,banana,NaN'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
print(df)
```

*Initial DataFrame*

```
    Fruit1  Fruit2  Fruit3
0   NaN     Apple   NaN
1   Pear    NaN     NaN
2   NaN     NaN     Orange
3   Mango   NaN     NaN
4   NaN     banana  NaN

df['New']=df.fillna('').sum(1)
print(df)
```

*Updated DataFrame*

```
    Fruit1  Fruit2  Fruit3  new
0   NaN     Apple   NaN     Apple
1   Pear    NaN     NaN     Pear
2   NaN     NaN     Orange  Orange
3   Mango   NaN     NaN     Mango
4   NaN     banana  NaN     banana
```